# Subdomain rewrite to static file directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve the following in an MVC5 app.

1. In the MVC site root, the is a subdirectory "Sites" where static files live. For instance, there might be static assets (HTML, JS, CSS) for "acme" and it is located under "/Sites/acme/"
2. Ideally, if you hit "acme.localhost" (in my dev environment) it will serve the contents of the /Sites/acme location, defaulting to index.html. So basically everything on the subdomain of acme will be rewritten to be relative to /Sites/acme. I have the DNS side of this all sorted out.
3. I know the IIS URL Rewrite module is designed to do this scenario, however the catch is users can define their subdomain in my MVC app dynamically (these are currently stored in a database). I don't know what they will be, and as far as I understand editing the rewriting in web.config if I were to do it this way will cause the parent MVC application pool to recycle. This makes me think it has to be some sort of HttpHandler that looks at a cached table of possible subdomains registered in the system and rewrites accordingly.

Any thoughts or suggestions? I was thinking a HTTP module or custom Route handler but not sure how to achieve this, and am very wary of doing this in an efficient way.

Thanks